# How to Collapse All Regions in Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-studio

I used to use SSMSBOOST in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
https://www.ssmsboost.com/

where it add "REGIONS" support to the editor, which is very helpful to organize the scripts.
But Recently with my switch to user Microsoft Azure Data Studio which is the best alternative (Visual Studio Code Like) editor,
I noticed they offer this feature of "Regions" as exactly the same syntax:

> --#region
> ... script here
> --#endregion

But the issue is how to collapse all regions in the file; either by some kind of command, or in the opening of the file as this is the default behavior for SSMSBoost add-ins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default its <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to fold all.

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to unfold all regions.

They can be rebound in File ► Preferences ► Keyboard Shortcuts, under 'Fold All', and 'Unfold All'.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to keyboard shortcuts, which I regularly forget if I don't use frequently enough, the command palette is also useful for this type of operation.

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and begin typing "fold" or "unfold". You'll see all sorts of other folding/unfolding options in addition to "Fold All" and "Unfold All"